# Find the greatest integer in the expression below as a function of the given conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the greatest integer less than $\sqrt{2^{100}+10^{10}}.$
**Answer**: $2^{50}$

I tried, but I can't finish:

$\sqrt{2^{100}+(2\cdot5)^{10}}=\sqrt{2^{10}(2^{90}+5^{10})}=2^5\sqrt{2^{90}+5^{10}}$

Comment: Hint:  what is $\left(2^{50}+1\right)^2$?

Comment: Title says *smallest*, but question body says *greatest*!?

Comment: $10^{10}$ is peanuts compared to $2^{100}$, so $2^{50}$ is a good answer to check using inequalities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little GM-AM can also be helpful:

\begin{eqnarray*} \sqrt{2^{100}+10^{10}}
& = & 2^{50} \sqrt{  1+\frac{10^{10}}{2^{100}}} \\
& \stackrel{GM-AM}{<} & 2^{50}\frac{1+1+\frac{10^{10}}{2^{100}}}2 \\
& = & 2^{50} + \frac{10^{10}}{2^{51}} \\
& < & 2^{50} + \frac{10^{10}}{2^{50}} \\
& = & 2^{50} + \left( \frac{10}{2^5}\right)^{10} \\
& < & 2^{50} + 1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 5):

It results that

$2^{50}=\sqrt{2^{100}}<\sqrt{2^{100}+10^{10}}<\sqrt{2^{100}+16^{10}}=$

$=\sqrt{2^{100}+2^{40}}<\sqrt{2^{100}+2^{51}+1}=\sqrt{\left(2^{50}+1\right)^2}=2^{50}+1$

Hence ,

$2^{50}<\sqrt{2^{100}+{10^{10}}}<2^{50}+1\;.$

Consequently,

$\left\lfloor\sqrt{2^{100}+10^{10}}\right\rfloor=2^{50}\;.$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Can you show that $\left(2^{50}\right)^2<2^{100}+10^{10}<\left(2^{50}+1\right)^2$?